# Named arrays without variables

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have a query, that looks like this:

```
select *
from foo
where bar in ("bla", "blub")
and anotherField in ("bla", "blub")
```

Is it possible to name the `("bla", "blub")` array and is it possible to name it without using `set` at the beginning?

Comment: **Why** would you want to do so?

Comment: Because I make a chat and want to select the hole conversation of two users. So the sender have to be UserA or UserB and the target have to be UserA or UserB. And I don't want to write these arrays twice.

Comment: **Why** do you not want "to write these arrays twice"?

Comment: Because there have to be an easier way.

Comment: Really?  It seems pretty easy to me.

Comment: Is it, but maybe it can be easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL variables can only hold its primitive datatypes.  There is no such thing as an array in MySQL, nor any ability to store multiple values in a variable.

So, the short answer to your question is "no, it is not possible".  But that isn't normally a big deal as your application usually constructs SQL using a higher level language, in which you may well hold such a collection in a variable: thus one can build the same `IN()` expression from that variable without having to repeat oneself to any significant extent.  This is essentially what [@NikhilButani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22141476) accomplishes via statement preparation.

That said, collections of values *can* be represented in SQL: after all, that's precisely what *tables* are.  So, you *can* get around this by storing your values in a table.  There are essentially three ways that this can be accomplished, none of which is "easier" (IMHO) than simply expressing the same list of literals to two `IN()` expressions and so I would not normally recommend them for your use case:

1. Create and populate a (possibly temporary) table, which you subsequently join to your query:

   ```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE vals (x VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
   INSERT INTO vals VALUES ('bla'), ('blub');

   SELECT *
   FROM   foo
     JOIN vals v1 ON v1.x = foo.bar
     JOIN vals v2 ON v2.x = foo.anotherField;
   ```
2. Use `UNION` to derive "inline" tables from subqueries:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   foo
     JOIN (SELECT 'bla' AS x UNION ALL SELECT 'blub') v1 ON v1.x = foo.bar
     JOIN (SELECT 'bla' AS x UNION ALL SELECT 'blub') v2 ON v2.x = foo.anotherField;
   ```
3. Define a view from the same `UNION` and then join that:

   ```
   CREATE VIEW vals AS SELECT 'bla' AS x UNION ALL SELECT 'blub';

   SELECT *
   FROM   foo
     JOIN vals v1 ON v1.x = foo.bar
     JOIN vals v2 ON v2.x = foo.anotherField;
   ```

It is also possible to hack around your problem with MySQL's `FIND_IN_SET()` function, as demonstrated in [@Stephan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22141512).  However, this is very much a "hack" that relies on your data having a particular form and will not scale well.

Comment: +1 for the multiple solutions which should work faster than `FIND_IN_SET()` alternative

Comment: A pity there is no easier way. I thought it could work with a syntax like `("bla", "blub") [as] NAME` and use `NAME` in the second condition. A pity there is no easier way... Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by preparing your `SQL` statement first like:

```
set @param:="'bla', 'blub'";


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT *  FROM foo WHERE bar IN (', @param, ')
     AND anotherField IN (', @param, ')');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: Beware to properly escape `@param` in order to prevent SQL injection, or accidental bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 'bla, blub' INTO @mstr;

SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    foo
WHERE 
    find_in_set(bar,@mstr)
    AND find_in_set(anotherField,@mstr)
```

Comment: Did you mean `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(bar,@mstr) AND FIND_IN_SET(anotherField, @mstr)`?  Beware that this will not work if `bar`, `anotherField` or the values in `@mstr` themselves contain comma characters.  Also, beware that such an approach is highly inefficient as it demands a full table scan in which string matching is performed against each record.

Comment: Also, `@mstr` should simply contain `'bla,blub'`.

Comment: @eggyal i know its inefficient ... i just offered an answer to the question which didn't mentioned any performance demands